# Problems with Json array

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, json.net

I'm writing a VB.Net application with an API to send values to a datasource.
My JSON output is made with NewtonSoft.Json like the following:

```
{
    "Id": null,
    "Name": "Werkkaart_tests",
    "ExternalId": "Werkkaart_test",
    "Headers": null,
    "Rows": null,
    "NewRows": ["val 1, val 2, val 3, val 4"],
    "DeletedRows": null,
    "CompanyId": 1111,
    "IntegrationKey": "lsfjlsfjlsfj3987"
}
```

With a PUT request I can update the datasource.
The model schema of the JSON is like this:

```
{
  "Id": "",
  "Name": "",
  "ExternalId": "",
  "Headers": [
    {
      "Name": "",
      "DisplayAt": ""
    }
  ],
  "Rows": [
    "Array[string]"
  ],
  "NewRows": [
    "Array[string]"
  ],
  "DeletedRows": [
    "Array[string]"
  ],
  "CompanyId": 0,
  "IntegrationKey": ""
}
```

The datasource has 4 columns named col1, col2, col3 and col4.
To add new rows to the datasource I have to make an Array of String in NewRows.

When I send my JSON-string columns 1 till 4 are filled with the following values:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val | 1 | val | 2 |

What I want is the following:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 |

I tried placing single quotes around my values, but that doesn't work.
I also tried the following:

```
"NewRows": ["val 1", "val 2", "val 3", "val 4"],
```

but the I get the following result:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val1 |  |  |  |
| val2 |  |  |  |
| val3 |  |  |  |
| val4 |  |  |  |

Here's the vb code:

```
Dim src As New DSS.DataSource
Dim values As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

values.Add("val 1") 
values.Add("val 2")
values.Add("val 3")

src.Name = "SourceName"
src.ExternalId = "Source_ExtID"

Dim newRowsString As String = String.Join(", ", values)
src.NewRows = New List(Of String) From {newRowsString} 

Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(src)
Console.WriteLine(json)
```

Comment: It would help if you provide your vb code

Comment: `"val 1, val 2, val 3, val 4"` <-- this is a single array item as JSON is concerned

Comment: You're mixing horizontal vs vertical. Your json attributes is horizontal data. Your Array values are vertical data. i.e. Array items are 1 records each. attributes - 1 field each

Comment: When I do a PUT-request like this: "val 1, val 2, val 3, val 4" it ffiling up the datasource like val | 1 | val | 2. I would suggest that it would be like val 1 | val 2 | val 3 | val 4.

Comment: you string join your values `String.Join(", ", values)`, it flattens it, hence you get them in 1 row

Comment: Yes, I know. That is the thing I want. But when there are spaces in my stringvalues, the stringvalues are splitted on the spaces and comma's.
So the datasource is filled like | value | 1 | value | 2 |.
I want the datasource to be filled like | value 1 | value 2 | value 3 | value 4 |

Comment: Is the new row supposed be an array itself?  i.e. should the resulting json be `"NewRows" : [["val 1", "val 2", "val 3", "val 4"]]`?

Comment: Hi @Craig, just tested it, and it works now. Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the type of `NewRows` is denoted as `"Array[String]"`.  But you are providing a scalar string i.e. `"val 1, val 2, val 3, val 4"`.  You should provide the values as separate strings inside an array, so that `NewRows` is an array of arrays, i.e. the resulting json should be  `"NewRows" : [["val 1", "val 2", "val 3", "val 4"]]`.

Each element in the outer array is a different row, each element of the inner array is a separate column within that particular row.